# selected при создании options через AJAX не работает на Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, form, select

Список из `option` и сам `select` создаётся через AJAX, в хроме работает отлично `selected`, а вот Firefox отказывается показывать первый пункт выбранный по дефолту. Он показывает пустоту.

Я пробовал такие варианты

**1.**

```
document.querySelector("#main-sorting select").setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
```

**2.**

```
document.querySelector("#main-sorting option").setAttribute('default', true);
```

**3.**

```
document.querySelector("#main-sorting option").setAttribute('selected', true);
```

**4.**

document.querySelector('#main-sorting select option').click()

**5.** Сделал див, в который вставляется селект в виде

```
<form name="custom-select" method="POST" id="main-sorting">
```

Ни один не работает.

Вот, что на выходе получается

```
<form autocomplete="off" name="custom-select" method="POST" id="main-sorting">
    <div class="ais-SortBy">
        <select class="ais-SortBy-select" autocomplete="off">
            <option class="ais-SortBy-option" value="val1" default="true" selected="true">Default sorting</option>
            <option class="ais-SortBy-option" value="val2">Sort by popularity</option>
            <option class="ais-SortBy-option" value="val3">Sort by average rating</option>
            <option class="ais-SortBy-option" value="val4">Sort by price: low to high</option>
            <option class="ais-SortBy-option" value="val5">Sort by price: high to low</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Я могу управлять только `<form autocomplete="off" name="custom-select" method="POST" id="main-sorting">`, а всё внутри идет с сервера. А так же, атрибуты `default="true" selected="true"` добавил скриптом уже после загрузки всего этого:

```
const send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() { 
    this.addEventListener('load', function() { 
         
        //add default option selected  
        document.querySelector("#main-sorting").querySelector('select').setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off'); 
        document.querySelector("#main-sorting option").setAttribute('default', true); 
        document.querySelector("#main-sorting option").setAttribute('selected', true); 
        document.querySelector('#main-sorting select option').click()
    return send.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте `document.querySelector("#main-sorting select").setAttribute('value', 'ЗНАЧЕНИЕ_OPTION_ПО_УМОЛЧАНИЮ')`

Comment: Покажи какой `html` создаешь. Как выглядит тот `select`?

Comment: @ksa добавил код, который используется

Comment: @SwaD не помогло, к сожалению

Comment: По умолчанию `select` "выберет" первый `option` из своего списка. А тебе какой `option` нужно выбрать?

Comment: @ksa первый попавшийся, к которому я и пытался прописать все атрибуты

Comment: FF будто не видит изменений после загрузки всего этого. А хром видит. Если я удалю свой код для атрибутов, то и в хроме тоже не будет выбранного по умолчанию. Поэтому, и думаю, что дело в FF

Comment: Если вообще ничег8о не писать - будут выбран первый `option` из списка.

Comment: @ksa нет, он ничего не выберет ни в одном браузере. Если бы select был статично вбит, то он бы брал первый и тему бы я не создавал)

Comment: У тебя как-то странно используется колбек у запроса... Для обработки ответа `XMLHttpRequest` используется `onreadystatechange `. У тебя же какой-то `load`...

Comment: @ksu я не могу получить ссылку запроса, т.к. этот код - это расширение шаблона плагина на WP, который перезаписывает файл плагина и он там сам связывает. Если я правильно понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотри все работает и выбирается без всяких танцев с бубнами...

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'https://fakerapi.it/api/v1/credit_cards?_quantity=10'
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState != 4) return;
  const os = document.createElement('select')
  let a = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
  a = a.data.forEach(o => {
    const oo = document.createElement('option')
    oo.textContent = o.owner
    os.append(oo)
  })
  document.querySelector('div').append(os)
}

xhr.send();
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Я взял за основу вашу идею и сделал свою. Я создал option свой кастомный и вставил в сгенерированный из сервера select (напомню, я не могу получить URL с сервера, т.к. это все плагин делает, я могу только добавить функционал, у вас немного другой подход) со всеми атрибутами и заработало в FF. Спасибо!